# Google Analytics 4, problem with URL (not set)

Tags: google-analytics

I am using the new Google Analytics 4, with automatic tracking.

I have some custom dimensions for "click" events, but "link_url" doesn't appear in the report. I can see the URL from "Real Time" if I click on "clicks", but with "Hub Analysis" then I cannot find that URL.

So if now I see URL "X" in "Real Time", tomorrow the same URL will be "(not set)". Why?

I have this problem with the new Google Analytics, with events "(not set)" in the report. I can see correct number for "clicks", but then I dont have the "link_url" parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me while to figure it out (documentation for this is poor).

> 1. **GA4** -> All Events -> Create Custom Dimensions -> set link_url (This step you did)
> 2. **Google Tag Manager** -> Variables -> Built-in variables -> Configure -> Check **Click URL**
> 3. Wait approximately 24 hours.

Comment: thanks, but how can I link GA4 to Tag Manager?

Comment: @totzi10, do you have Tag Manager installed on your site?

Comment: I need to put also the TM's script into website? I have only GA4. Then I have to create a new tag?

Comment: @totzi10 - I'll not say with 100% it is necessary, but I will say, that it works for me :)

BTW - when you'll get GTM working on your website it can also serve GA4 code - then you'll have everything in one place.

Comment: So do I need 2 scripts (GTM and GA4) or 1?

Comment: I think that you can have both, but if you have GTM, it is easy to add GA4 inside GTM. It's up to you.

I, presonally use only GTM with GA4 set up inside GTM.

Comment: How can I set GA4 inside GTM?

Comment: Ok... This you can find in google. But there you go. I'll google it for you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_wq5nfKQ3DM